# Session conflict between multiple users

Tags: java

I use java 1.7 with an old echoStudido framework.
I have a sessionManager class like this in a webservice located on a GlassFish server:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class SessionManager {
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
    private long ttl = 30 * 60 * 1000L;
    private HashMap<String, UserSession> sessions = new HashMap<String, UserSession>();

public UserSession getSession(String sessionId) {
    synchronized (this) {
        UserSession session = sessions.get(sessionId);
        if (session == null) {
            return null;
        }
        session.setLastAccess(new Date());
        return session;
    }
}

public String addSession(Integer userId, String userName) {
    String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    UserSession session = new UserSession(sessionId, userId, userName);
    synchronized (this) {
        if (sessions.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "session pool has exceeded the capacity of {0}"
                    + "-session creation rejected for user {1}",
                    new Object[]{MAX_SIZE, userName});
            return null;
        }
        sessions.put(sessionId, session);
    }
    return sessionId;
}

public UserSession removeSession(String sessionId) {
    synchronized (this) {
        return sessions.remove(sessionId);
    }
}
}
```

This is how looks the bean class:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName="MyAppWebService", portName="PortalPort")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class PortalBean {

private static final String SESSION_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME
        = "com.myapp.portal.sessionId";

public String getSessionId() {
    return (String) getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
}

private String getValidSessionId() {
    String sessionId = getSessionId();
    if (sessionId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return sessionId;
}

public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    getSession().setAttribute(SESSION_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, sessionId);
}
....
}
```

During the login process, i run this code in the bean class:

```
String sessionId = sessionManager.addSession(user.getId(), user.getEmail());
```

then:

```
setSessionId(sessionId);
```

When two users are logged in, if I click on logout(sessionManager.removeSession(sessionId);) and runs the removeSession method, the other user's session is removed too.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you know how the SessionManager is instatiated? Is there a new SessionManager() somewhere in your code? I must admint, I am unfamiliar with echoStudio(d) but I you try making the sessions attribute static (private static HashMap<String, UserSession> sessions = ...) because the sessions actually are static. In that case you would have to synchronize over a static log, tho. good luck!

Comment: the sessionManager is set like this: 
    @EJB
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

Comment: I have already tried to make the sessions static, but it doesn't help

Comment: does the removeSession method return the correct UserSession object with the correct sessionId in it?

Comment: if it does return the correct value you can check if UUID.randomUUID().toString() is thread safe and creates different results. I would leave the sessions attribute static anyway. Need to go, sorry

Comment: It returns the correct sessionId, after that, the getSessionId of the other user returns null

Comment: can you use the debugger to check if the sessions map contains both values before removing one of them?